# How to create a new decimal accuracy for subtotal in sale order odoo 9

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and i have created in Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy-> Account with digits 3 for subtotal rounding. Then i have added in **sale.py**  `price_subtotal = fields.Monetary(compute='_compute_amount', string='Subtotal', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'))`
. After that i updated the two modules **sale** and **decimal_precision**. But when i create a new saleorder there is no change in the subtotal rounding it display 2 digits instead of 3. Any help please i'm stuck with this problem for days now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the parser tries to get the precision of the monetary field, first it looks for `digits` attribute.

So to change the decimal precision you can add `digits`attribute to the xml view.

```
<record id="view_order_form_precision_3" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.order.form.precision</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr='//tree/field[@name="price_subtotal"]' position="attributes">
            <attribute name="digits">(14, 3)</attribute>
        </xpath>

        <field name="amount_untaxed" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="digits">(14, 3)</attribute>
        </field>

        <field name="amount_tax" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="digits">(14, 3)</attribute>
        </field>

        <field name="amount_total" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="digits">(14, 3)</attribute>
        </field>

    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to modify the type of fields from **Monetary** to **Float** :
 `price_subtotal = fields.Float(compute='_compute_amount', string='Subtotal', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'))`